# How to create a crescent moon border radius in rectangle right side?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a button like this

[image]

i just don't know what to search for me to create a shape like this.

this is so far what i have.

```css
.rectangle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #555;
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
}

.radius_rectangle {
  width: 90px;
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 0px 40px 40px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle">
  <div class="radius_rectangle">
  </div>
</div>
```

I appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Seems awfully close to me, just add the border radius to the outside container, right?

Comment: @ggorlen yes. i just don't know how to do it. making the corner rounded is easy. but making the whole left side of the rectangle to be shape like a moon is really confusing to me sir.

Comment: Does the existing answer do it or did you want to produce something exactly like the image you see with the right side being the curved inner button? Try to be a bit more specific about what you need and see [Why is "can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there.
Set `overflow:hidden` to `.rectangle`, note the `border-radius` corners. Also you need to move `.radius_rectangle` to the right -- I used `margin-left:auto`. Anonther way is setting `text-align:right` to `.rectangle`.

```css
.rectangle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #555;
  border-radius: 40px 0 0 40px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #000;
}

.radius_rectangle {
  width: 130px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 40px 0 0 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle">
  <div class="radius_rectangle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: OMGGGGG. thank you very much sir. i just really don't know what to search on creating this shape. thank you for the help sir.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.rectangle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #555;
  border-radius: 0px 40px 40px 0px;
}

.radius_rectangle{
    width: 90px;
    background: red;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 0px 40px 40px 0px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<div class="rectangle">

<div class="radius_rectangle">

</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done it using extra div element

```
<div class="rectangle">
  <div class="radius_rectangle">
  </div>
  <div class="foo"></div>
</div>
```

```
.rectangle {
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 40px 0px 0px 40px;
}

.radius_rectangle {
  width: 90px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 40px 0px 0px 40px;
}

.foo {
  width: 110px;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 40px 0px 0px 40px;
}
```